# Angular Js: Select box set selected value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, selected

I have a select box,

```
 <select populate-details ng-model="properties.maxRetries.type" ng-options="value as text for (text, value) in presentation.sources.maxR_Source"></select>
```

directive to populate about selectbox:

```
    angular.module("test.directives").directive("populateDetails", function() {
      return {
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
          scope.presentation.sources.maxR_Source = {
            "Hours": "4",
            "Minutes": "5",
            "Seconds": "6"
          };
        }
      };
    });
```

I want to make the option "Minutes" as selected initially. How can i go that?

Please help,
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the controller, set `$scope.properties.maxRetries.type = 'Minutes'`.  Then your ng-model will pick up the value and apply it to the options.